# Chemical analysis to detect oil burning in emissions

Tags: oil, oil-leak, emissions

Is it possible to chemically analyze an engine's emissions to detect presence of oil in the fuel? I am losing a lot of oil but it's not dripping when running to indicate a leak. So I would like some chemical analysis to support for or against the suspicion of burning.

Comment: So proper lab, with all equipment? Or as is much more likely you have a bonfire, old dented saucepan and a twig for stirring?

Comment: What is " a lot" oil ? In the 50's and 60's it would be common for an older car to burn a quart ( 0.94 L) every 500 miles. One just put in more oil.  So one could burn that much with no obvious evidence.  There may be a slight blue cloud , but may not have been obvious which car made most of it.  For your analysis you would need a base line for the motor oil;   heavy elements in the additives would be about all there is to find. I am obsolete but years ago it would have been Ba, Zn, Ca and Mg.

Comment: Many places in the world have "smog checks" to evaluate vehicle emissions.  Perhaps a smog check facility could provide you with your vehicle's emissions data.

Comment: @blacksmith37 like 4 qt per 1K mi -- a lot. I just want to check if there is oil in the exhaust

Comment: If there is no sign of an oil leak and it is not going in your coolant, which doesn’t seem possible seeing as you are loosing a lot, then it must be getting burnt.  It seems a waste of money getting a test done.

Comment: I have heard of cars burning amounts like one quart in a 200 miles , they have a noticeable blue cloud of exhaust. At that time some service stations would sell drained motor from oil changes very cheap for heavy users ( Chicago , 1950's)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but it requires special equipment called an "Exhaust Gas Analyzer".  Call around to some local shops to find one that has such a setup.

They can detect excess oil, coolant, and other issues.  Many state emission testing centers use these also.

Here is a link that describes some of the measurements that these can make:

[Exhaust Analyzer](https://www.walkerexhaust.com/support/tech-tips/five-gas-diagnostic-chart.html)

Specifically it says:

> High CO levels indicate partially burnt fuel or oil

You can also often tell there is excess oil being burned by inspecting the spark plugs.  An oily and carbon-encrusted electrode is a good indication of an oil burning problem.